# Fill an associative array with values to initialise

Tags: php

I have the following array:

```
array(
    'elem1', 'elem2', 'elem3'
);
```

I want to have the following:

```
array(
    'elem1' => 0,
    'elem2' => 0,
    'elem3' => 0
);
```

is this possible with `array_fill`? I cant see that it is.

If not, is there a way to do this without iterating over the array?

Comment: http://php.net/array_fill_keys

Answer (score 11):

Yup.. Try this

```
<?php
$keys = array('elem1', 'elem2', 'elem3');
$a = array_fill_keys($keys, 0);
print_r($a);
?>
```

Output:

```
array(
    'elem1' => 0,
    'elem2' => 0,
    'elem3' => 0
);
```